# Converting bitmap to vector in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, vector, bitmap

I have been trying to convert a bitmap I've captured from a camera input into a vector to then convert the vectors points into an array for use later.

However I can not find any such functionality within Flash and so I've been trying to use 'Vectorization Package' created by [Corey O'Neil](http://coreyoneil.com). This seems to work but fails to remove the white background on my bitmap (I am capturing a picture of paper with a line on it). Even manually doing this and making the background transparent still yields no results.

Here is my code:

```
public class DocumentRich extends MovieClip{

    public var initBox2D:Main;
    var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); 
    var vid:Video = new Video(420, 300); 
    var myVector:Vectorize;
    public function DocumentRich()
    {
        if(stage){
            initBox2D = new Main();
            addChild(initBox2D);
            //addChild(new movieMonitor());
        } 

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler, false, 0, true);
        StartAnim();


    }

    function StartAnim():void
    {
        //SET UP WORLD
        initBox2D.isDebugMode(false);
        initBox2D.mouseDragEnabled(true);
        Main.world.SetGravity(new b2Vec2(0,0));


        cam.setQuality(0, 100);
        cam.setMode(420, 300, 30, true);
        trace(cam.height);
        vid.attachCamera(cam); 
        addChild(vid);
        addChild(go);
    }

    function clickHandler(m:MouseEvent){
        trace(m.target.name);
        switch(m.target.name){
            case 'go':
                goButtonFun();
            break;

        }
    }

    function goButtonFun():void{
        var screenShot:BitmapData = new BitmapData(cam.width, cam.height); 
        var screenShot_image:Bitmap=new Bitmap(screenShot);
        screenShot.draw(vid) ;
        ReduceColors.reduceColors(screenShot, 0, true, false);
        screenShot.colorTransform(new Rectangle(0, 0, screenShot.width, screenShot.height), new ColorTransform(2,2,2,1) );

        ///// --------- MAY NOT NEED THIS ----------- ////////////
        for(var i:int = 0; i<screenShot.width; i++)
        {
            for(var j:int = 0; j<screenShot.height; j++)
            {
                if(screenShot.getPixel(i,j) == 0xffffff)
                {
                    var transparent:uint = 0x00000000;
                    screenShot.setPixel32(i, j, transparent);
                }
            }
        }

        myVector = new Vectorize(screenShot_image, 23, 2, 1, 3, 0xFFFFFF);
        myVector.addEventListener(Vectorize.INIT, traceStatus);
        myVector.addEventListener(Vectorize.DESPECKLE_START, traceStatus);
        myVector.addEventListener(Vectorize.DESPECKLE_COMPLETE, traceStatus);
        myVector.addEventListener(Vectorize.GROUPING_START, traceStatus);
        myVector.addEventListener(Vectorize.GROUPING_COMPLETE, traceStatus);
        myVector.addEventListener(Vectorize.EDGING_START, traceStatus);
        myVector.addEventListener(Vectorize.EDGING_COMPLETE, traceStatus);

        myVector.addEventListener(Vectorize.DESPECKLE_PROGRESS, traceProgress);
        myVector.addEventListener(Vectorize.GROUPING_PROGRESS, traceProgress);
        myVector.addEventListener(Vectorize.EDGING_PROGRESS, traceProgress);

        myVector.addEventListener(Vectorize.COMPLETE, showVector);
        myVector.vectorize();

        //addChild(screenShot_image);
        addChild(go);
        removeChild(vid);
        cam = null;
        vid.attachCamera(null);
        vid = null;
    }

    function traceStatus(event:Event):void
    {
        trace(event.type);
    }
    function traceProgress(event:Event):void
    {
        var progress:int = event.target.percentDone * 100;
        trace(event.type + ": " + progress + "%");
    }
    function showVector(event:Event):void
    {
        trace(event.type);
        addChild(myVector);
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry for any confusion, basically I would like a way to trace a transparent bitmap, and get an array of the points of the shape in said bitmap. An array of pixel data is simply too large... I'd like 4 points for a rectangle, regardless of it's size...

Comment: You say you are vectorizing a picture of a paper with a line on it, yet it's not likely that it's color value is #ffffff. Does the library have a tolerance setting ?

Comment: I am converting the image into black and white using these lines:
`ReduceColors.reduceColors(screenShot, 0, true, false);

 screenShot.colorTransform(new Rectangle(0, 0, screenShot.width, screenShot.height), new ColorTransform(2,2,2,1) );`

Comment: Have you verified that these two lines results in an image with just black and white ? Not just visually, but have you verified that they color values in the bitmapData are what you expect them to be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are looking for [BitmapData.getVector()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getVector%28%29). It's available from Flash player 10, so you should have it at your disposal.

EDIT: After I've reread your question, I understand you want your bitmap to be parsed into a vector - and a vector isn't an array of pixels, but instead a start and end of a certain line. Then yes, if you are capable of calling a `threshold()` so that the line's pixels will be of one color, and the background of another, you then can call `getColorBoundsRect()` and query all 4 corners of the rectangle. The ones which have the color of the line are your start and end coordinates, store these.

Comment: But this requires inputting a rectangle area parameter? I don't know where on the page the line will be and so i can't specify a location for the rectangle... Unless this can be used without parameters and it ignores transparent pixels?

Comment: Experimenting with this seems to give a huge array of points which don't make sense. the array has over 300,000 numbers in it...

Comment: Well, giving it a rectangle means what part of the image you want exported as vector. And you apparently want to parse a line out of an image with correct coordinates for start and end - I'm not sure if there was a functinoal for this. You can attempt to call `getColorBoundsRect()` if your line is straight, then one of the pairs of opposite angles will net you the start&end coordinates. Otherwise, you have to parse a line somehow trickier.

Comment: Thanks, Vesper, that works :)

Do you have any idea how it could be expanded to multiple shapes on the page? So a rectangle can be created for each shape separately?

Comment: Well, image recognition is a whole different part, and has a tremendous lot of difficulties. You can attempt to search the longest line at a given angle from a point that you discover being say topmost non-background, and if you've found that the line continues, you can recursively search forward. Past this I don't yet have ideas about what can you do to find say closed shapes, or say 8-like shapes.